# Regex if then else confusion

Tags: regex

I have a problem with the Regex-If-then-else logic:

I am trying to achieve the following:

If the string contains the substring `PubDSK` then do the Regex Expression
`^[\s\S]{24}(?=.{10}([\s\S]*))0*(.*?)(?=\1)[\s\S]*`

If it does NOT contain the substring `PubDSK` then do a different Regex Expression, namely `^[\s\S]{48}(?=.{10}([\s\S]*))0*(.*?)(?=\1)[\s\S]*`

I am using this Regex Expression `(?(?=^.*PubDSK.*$)^[\s\S]{24}(?=.{10}([\s\S]*))0*(.*?)(?=\1)[\s\S]*|^[\s\S]{48}(?=.{10}([\s\S]*))0*(.*?)(?=\1)[\s\S]*)`

The affirmative case works great: https://regex101.com/r/ab9yOv/

BUT the non-affirmative case, doesn't do the trick: https://regex101.com/r/azxGvh/1

I assume it doesn't match so it cannot do the replacement?? How can I tell the regex to do the replacement on the complete string in the ELSE case?

I understand, that this problem can be easily solved with any other programming language, but for this use case I can only use pure regex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `\1` backreference refers to the first capturing group *of the entire regex*. So, it does not refer to the right capturing group defined in the *else* pattern part. In fact, the second `\1` must be replaced with `\3` as it refers to the third capturing group.

Also, note that `(?=\1)` and `(?=\3)` lookaheads make little sense here as they are followed with `[\s\S]*` consuming patterns. Just remove the lookahead pattern and use consuming ones.

The fixed pattern looks like

```regex
(?(?=^.*PubDSK.*$)^[\s\S]{24}(?=.{10}([\s\S]*))0*(.*?)\1[\s\S]*|^[\s\S]{48}(?=.{10}([\s\S]*))0*(.*?)\3[\s\S]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/azxGvh/2).